# Craft Equivelent of EE addon CE Image Bulk Tag?

Tags: image-transforms, migration

I'm preparing to migrate an old ExpressionEngine site to Craft and there are channels with images that are being resized by wrapping the rich text editor with [ce image bulk tag](https://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-image/user-guide/basics.html#bulk-tag-in-depth) like this:

```
{exp:ce_img:bulk attributes="class='img-responsive'"}
 {brand_copy}
{/exp:ce_img:bulk}
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish the same thing in Craft.. apply bulk transforms to images in a  rich text editor?

Need this for legacy content that will be moved in with feedme, new content will have a matrix set up using a different entry type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing using the [Retcon plugin](https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft) for Craft. Have a look at the [wiki entry for the `transform` filter](https://github.com/mmikkel/Retcon-Craft/wiki/Transform) for more details.